# How do I delete a specific parameter from URL without deleting other parameters with the same key?

Tags: javascript, url, location-href, urlsearchparams

I've got this code working fine. But The `delete()` function deletes all entries with the `key` equal to "foo".

```
`let url = new URL("https://example.com?foo=1&bar=2");
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

 //Add a second foo parameter.
 url.searchParams.append("foo", 4);

 console.log(params.getAll("foo")); //Prints ["1","4"].
 console.log(url)
 url.searchParams.delete("foo", 4);
 console.log(url)`
```

The goal is to delete only one of entry (foo=4) and

Answer (score 0):

How about using indexof?

```
// Find the index of the entry to delete.
let index = params.getAll("foo").indexOf("4");

// If the value was found, remove it.
if (index !== -1) {
  params.getAll("foo").splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` option in delete method is not being supported by major browsers other than Firefox, and Node.js only supports the syntax starting from version 20. One way to resolve it is to get all values associated with the search parameter `url.searchParams.getAll("foo")`, filter out the one with undesired value, delete all search parameters with the name `foo`, and finally add the desired ones back.